# How do I write a formula to code numbers into letters?

Tags: google-sheets

We work in gemstones and would like to figure out a formula for codifying the prices. This would depend on the client we could adjust the price without them seeing our baseline.

$1710 would show on the tag: 1GA0.

Essentially, the alphabet would be assigned to the numbers, we'd like to keep the first digit but anything after that would be a letter.

Is there a way to do this in google sheets to generate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the following are true:

1.) Your raw price data runs `A2:A`.

2.) Your raw price data are actual numbers.

Use the following array formula in the second cell of an otherwise empty column:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,REGEXREPLACE(LEFT(A2:A)&TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(MID(A2:A&REPT("~",10),2,10),"(.)","$1~"),"~")&""="0",0,CHAR(64+SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(MID(A2:A&REPT("~",10),2,10),"(.)","$1~"),"~"))))," ",10)),"\s|@","")))`

This will produce all converted results for `A2:A`.

As this is a unique custom formula that will not be often requested by future site visitors, and since it is rather complex, I'm providing it as-is and without explanation at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

#### Formula for B1:

`=JOIN("", LEFT(A1, 1), ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, MID(A1, ROW($A$2:INDIRECT("A" & LEN(A1))), 1) * 1, 4), "1", ""), "0")))`

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Step by step formula behavior:

[image: behaviour]

- Step 1: splits the 2nd digit to the last digit into separate cells
- Step 2: convert valid numbers (1-9) into letters
- Step 3: convert `#VALUE` to "0"
- Step 4: combine the 1st number and the converted value.

#### Note:

- 1st number and zeroes are as is, everything else is converted.
- If `$` is a necessity and is present together with a `,`, then adjust your formula into:

#### Adjusted formula:

`=JOIN("", MID(TO_TEXT(A1), "2", "1"), ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, MID(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A1), ",", ""), ROW($A$3:INDIRECT("A" & LEN(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A1), ",", "")))), 1) * 1, 4), "1", ""), "0")))`

#### Adjustments:

- `LEFT(A1, 1)` -> `MID(TO_TEXT(A1), "2", "1")`

  - since we consider the `$`, we need to get the 2nd character instead of the first 1.
- `A1` -> `REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A1), ",", "")`

  - since getting the value directly will yield to a number but the length will result into the string's length, we need to compare them equally, thus converting the number into text and then removing the `,` to return the proper value as string.
- `$A$2` -> `$A$3`

  - we start to convert the third character instead of the 2nd.

Adjusted formula now should yield the following output:

[image: output]

#### References:

- [Convert number to letter](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/convert-column-number-to-letter-in-google-sheets/)
- [Split number into digits](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/split-number-to-digits-in-google-sheets/)